# How to capture several documents together in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How can I capture several documents together in mongoose My code looks like this:

```js
router.get("/invstor/:token", async (req, res) => {
    const inv = await invstor.find({userID: req.params.token});
    res.send(inv);
});
```

So I try to grab by token all the documents of the same user.
In mongo db I would use find and it grabs all the documents.
My question is how can mongoose catch everything?

Comment: Mongoose also has a [Model.find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) method, you can look up all the queries available in [Mongoose - Queries](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)